# Typescript and destructuring array

Tags: typescript

I have this problem with typescript and can not understand what is wrong:

```
type Dogs = {bark: true};
type Cats = {meow: true};

........
.then((data: [Dogs, Cats][]) => {
  const [dogs, cats] = data;
  display(dogs, cats));
})
........

const display = (dogs: any, cats: any) => {
  return ....
}
```

For now, everything is ok. When *display* function is written like this (dogs: any, cats: any) everything is fine, but if I change *display* function to:

```
const display = (dogs: Dogs, cats: Cats) => {
  return ....
}
```

I receive an error in destructuring line (const [dogs, cats] = data;) that "dogs doesn't have meow key and cats doesn't have bark key"???

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `.then((data: [Dogs, Cats]) => {` you miswrote your type

Comment: `data: [Dogs, Cats][]` is an *array of tuples*, each tuple is `[Dogs, Cats]`. If you destructure as `const [dogs, cats] = data;` then `dogs` will hold *the first tuple* and `cats` will hold *the second tuple*. I'm not sure what you need but it's likely not an array of tuples. Either a plain tuple or an array.

Comment: Inside your `then` you are trying to deconstruct **array of arrays** into two variables. Each variable interpreted like array. So you should try just `data: [Dogs, Cats]`.

Comment: No, it is typed correctly.

Comment: data: [Dogs, Cats] does not work.

Answer (score 2):

`data` is an array of `[Dog, Cat]`, so destructuring `const [dogs, cats] = data;` would lead to assign the first element of `data` to `dogs` and second element to `cats`. ie, extracted value `dogs` is of type `[Dog, Cat]`. And extracted `cats` is of type `[Dog, Cat]`.

`const [dog, cat] = data[0];`

would correctly destructure to give correct dog and cat value. If you are tying to get the collection of dogs and cats into separate arrays, you can use `reduce`.

```
type Dogs = {bark: true};
type Cats = {meow: true};

const data: [Dogs, Cats][] = [[{bark: true}, {meow: true}]]

const display = (dogs: Dogs, cats: Cats) => {
  return 'dummy'
}

let result: {dogs: Dogs[], cats: Cats[]} = {dogs: [], cats: []};

data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const [dog, cat] = curr;
  
  acc.dogs.push(dog);
  acc.cats.push(cat);
  return acc
}, result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `data` parameter of `then` is an *array* of a tuple `[Dogs, Cats]`. If this is intended, you need to pick an item before deconstruction:

```
const [dogs, cats] = data[0];
```

If this is not intended, just annotate the type as a tuple:

```
.then((data: [Dogs, Cats])
```